# Rotate Object to the Same Direction as a Vector or Line

Tags: java, vector, 3d, processing

I need to rotate the rectangle in the following code to align with the line, as in the smaller faces of the rectangle are facing the ends of the line. How wold a rotation of a rectangle to a line or vector work in processing?

[image: Rectangle to rotate to line's direction]

```
import peasy.*;

int r = int(random(0, 256));
int g = int(random(0, 256));
int b = int(random(0, 256));


void setup() {

  size(430, 760, P3D);
  frameRate(60);

  PeasyCam cam = new PeasyCam(this, 0, 0, 0, 2000);
  cam.setMinimumDistance(50);
  cam.setMaximumDistance(2000);

}

void draw() {
  ambientLight(128, 128, 128);
  background(28);
  
  stroke(color(r,  g, b));

  line(-500, -500, -500, 500, 500, 500);
  
  box(200, 50, 50);

}
```

Comment: User Rabbid76 already answered this a couple of years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669771/calculate-rotation-to-align-object-with-two-points-in-3d-space . (Wish the search worked a bit better to get you there sooner).